# How to have exact decimal values without rounding in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, rounding

I have this SQL script below:

```
select round (72.396, 2)
```

What I expect like result is: **72.39.**

I don't want to round the number.

if I use the `select round(72.396, 2)` the result I get is: **72,40**
How can I have what I expect without rounding using Mysql?

[image]

Comment: Which rounding algorithm are you looking for? Why should that result be exactly `72.39` - which rules do apply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`truncate`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) function instead of `round`:

```sql
SELECT TRUNCATE(72.396, 2)
```

To answer the question in the comment - `truncate` just removes any additional decimal places after the number specified in the second argument, without rounding.

Comment: thx that just works...could you please explain what does the Truncate function?

Comment: @Gladiador sure, edited my answer with the additional info.